# Metadata list (MD5, modified time, size, path) for large directories/files in Python

Tags: python, windows, timestamp, metadata, md5

I am assembling a script to fingerprint up to 8TB directories with over 1 million files (including some files ~50 GB), and export the result into a .csv, such as, "**md5**","**LastWriteTime**","**filesize**","**fullpath\file.ext**":

```
"md5","YYYYMMDDHHMMSS","12345","A:\aaa\bb\c\file1.ext"
```

I am stuck with the coding, getting the output .csv empty:

```
def md5(fname):
    hash_md5 = hashlib.md5()
    with open(fname, "rb") as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(2 ** 20), b""):
            hash_md5.update(chunk)
    return hash_md5.hexdigest()
    def getSize(filename):
    st = os.stat(filename)
    return st.st_size()
    with open('md5_filelist.csv', 'w') as md5_filelist:
    file.write('hash_md5.hexdigest','timestamp','st.st_size','os.path.abspath')te')
```

What are the bits I am doing wrong (I am new to Python)? Thank you.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: `  File "C:\SCRIPTS\md5.py", line 7
    with open('md5_filelist.csv', 'w') as md5_filelist:
                                                      ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation`

Comment: That means that you are using spaces and tabs to indent your python code. You can only use one or the other, otherwise it will give you this error.

Comment: thanks! now i am getting empty .csv (but no error msg).

Comment: You are never writing to `md5_filelist`

Comment: that's certainly possible. what i am missing?  the PS equivalent: `export-csv file.csv -notypeinformation`

Comment: To write to an opened file in python you use `file.write('string to write')`

Comment: Also, where did `input` come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This Again:

```
import hashlib
import os
import time

your_target_folder = "."


def get_size(filename):
    st = os.stat(filename)
    return str(st.st_size)


def get_last_write_time(filename):
    st = os.stat(filename)
    convert_time_to_human_readable = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(st.st_mtime))
    return convert_time_to_human_readable


def get_md5(fname):
    hash_md5 = hashlib.md5()
    with open(fname, "rb") as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(2 ** 20), b""):
            hash_md5.update(chunk)
    return hash_md5.hexdigest()


for dirpath, _, filenames in os.walk(your_target_folder):

    for items in filenames:

        file_full_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, items))

        try:

            my_last_data = get_md5(file_full_path) + ", " + get_last_write_time(file_full_path) + ", " + get_size(
                file_full_path) + ", " + file_full_path + "\n"

            with open("md5_filelist.csv", "a") as my_save_file:
                my_save_file.write(my_last_data)

            print(str(file_full_path) + "  ||| Done")

        except:
            print("Error On " + str(file_full_path))
```

i changed fullpathaddress method and i added time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(st.st_mtime)) for convert that time to human readable format.

Good Luck ...

Comment: Thank you, this is nice! I **left line 5 as it is** `"."`, as I am running this from within the directory (which often changes per the actual task). Two small problems: (i) the **timestamp** (in Windows) appears like this: `1424316324.6933541` for an actual LastWriteTime (last modified date YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) `2015-02-19 03:25:24`, and (ii) it does not print the **full path** for files in subdirs.  (I tried also adding the target dir to line 5, but then no output file at all, only displayed in the command window with error msg)

Comment: @user3026965: Done! try it again :) and tick me plz.